# Realizar slick en div que se agrega de forma dinamica

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo esta función que agrega un div al dar click en una clase

```
$('.Color').click(function(e) {
    $('.product--images').append('<div class="product--images__thumbs product--images__thumbs01"></div>');
    $('.product--images').append('<div class="product--images__full product--images__full01"></div>');
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

ahora lo que quiero hacer es que después de agregarse el div, se ejecute otra función para darle el deslizamiento slick.
Intente darle un tiempo de espera con el setTimeout o el setInterval, no fue el caso, lo otro fue darle una condición que cuando exista la clase "product--images__thumbs01" se agregue el slick pero tampoco fue el caso.

```
if ($('.product--images__thumbs01').length) {
    $('.product--images__full01').slick({
        arrows: !0,
        dots: !1,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        asNavFor: ".product--images__thumbs01",
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 640,
            settings: {
                arrows: !1
            }
        }]
    });
    $('.product--images__thumbs01').slick({
        arrows: !1,
        dots: !1,
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        focusOnSelect: !0,
        vertical: !0,
        asNavFor: ".product--images__full01",
        responsive: [{
            breakpoint: 640,
            settings: {
                arrows: !1
            }
        }]
    });
}
```

Cabe mencionar que al hacerlo con el if(lenght) me sale lo siguiente.

"Cannot read property 'add' of null"

De que otra forma se podría lograr?

Gracias.